# how to use internal Storage in DatabaseHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite, file

I want to use internal storage (`opennFileOutput`) in database helper. 
This is my code:

```
public class DBDAO {
    protected SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    public DBDAO(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    }
    public void WriteFile(String writeString) {
        // add-write text into file
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileout = openFileOutput("language.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
            outputWriter.write(writeString);
            outputWriter.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
// Read text from file
    public String ReadFile() {
        // reading text from file
        String s = "";
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("language.txt");
            InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
            char[] inputBuffer = new char[100];
            int charRead;
            while ((charRead = InputRead.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                // char to string conversion
                String readstring = String
                        .copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                s += readstring;
            }
            InputRead.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

But, error in: **OpenFileOutput : MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable**

and: **The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type DBDAO**

So somebody can show me how to solve it?

Thanks so much and sorry because my english.

Answer (score 0):

`openFileInput()`, `openFileOutput()`, `MODE_PRIVATE`, etc. are defined on `Context`. Use `mContext.openFileInput()`, `mContext.openFileOutput()`, `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`, etc.